# Front Derailleur / Gears not working

Tags: derailleur

When I push the lever to change up the chainrings, I physically can't push it as it is like something is making it stuck, so I tried loosening the cable but had to do this so much that when I pushed the lever it did move but the cable was so loose the derailleur did not move at all, Please help me?
Thanks

Comment: When you try to move the derailer with your thumb, what keeps it from moving?  Are the limit screws too tight?  Is the cable binding?  Is the derailer so rusty it won't move?

Comment: Clean the FD. Put a drop of oil on each articulation, thin sewing machine oil not WD40 or similar products.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Are you the same user as [Charlie](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/57711/charlie)?  If so you might want to [merge your accounts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Probably a continuation of your previous question at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77813/gear-problems-small-chainring-to-big-chainring   - closing as duplicate.

Comment: Please don't create multiple accounts.  Use the Charlie username created first.